# Nested List to Dictionary and back again

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data structured like this:

```
[["ID", "Header1", "Header2"], [1, "a1", "a2"], [2, "b1", "b2"]]
```

I want to be able to convert this to a dictionary (or maybe pandas dataframe?) that looks like this (or has constant lookup for ID).

```
{
  1: {
    "Header1": "a1",
    "Header2": "a2",
  },
  2: {
    "Header1": "b1",
    "Header2": "b2",
  }
}
```

But here is the tricky part.... after doing some processing (lets say adding a 3rd id and dictionary), I need to be able to convert it back to a nested list with the headers in the same order.

```
[["ID", "Header1", "Header2"], [1, "a1", "a2"], [2, "b1", "b2"], [3, "c1", "c2"]]
```

Is there a simple way of doing this in pandas?  Or is dictionary the way to go?

Comment: "or has constant lookup for ID" um, does each ID follow the same pattern here? i.e. increasing integers? Can there be duplicates? If no duplicates, then this is just: `{id_: dict(Header1=h1, Header2=h2) for id_, h1, h2 in data[1:]}`

Comment: ids are always integers but are not monotonically increasing.  But there are no duplicates, ids are always unique.

Comment: This is a good comprehension to get from nested list to dict, but going in the opposite direction is more of a challenge.

Comment: Assuming you keep the header around, you can just do something like `[data[0], *[[k, *v.values()] for k,v in transformed.items()]]`

Answer (score 2):

With [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) you can use:

```
l = [["ID", "Header1", "Header2"], [1, "a1", "a2"], [2, "b1", "b2"]]

d = pd.DataFrame(l[1:], columns=l[0]).set_index('ID').to_dict('index')

print(d)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, 'index').rename_axis('ID').reset_index()
l2 = [list(df.columns)]+df.values.tolist()

print(l2)
```

Output:

```
{1: {'Header1': 'a1', 'Header2': 'a2'},
 2: {'Header1': 'b1', 'Header2': 'b2'}}

[['ID', 'Header1', 'Header2'],
 [1, 'a1', 'a2'],
 [2, 'b1', 'b2']]
```

A one liner version of the conversion to list (a bit hacky):

```
l2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, 'index').rename_axis('ID').reset_index().T.reset_index().T.values.tolist()
```

Comment: Would you say pandas is the most efficient way to go?  Or would a non-pandas answer like below or something like numpy work better?

Comment: Honestly, you have to test. `pandas` will add an overhead, so it will certainly be slower on small datasets. Might be faster on large ones, and more convenient if you also need to do some processing. You should test and see how this fits in your pipeline. I used pandas here because you had the tag ;)

Answer (score 1):

Other answers have shown how to use pandas for that purpose.
I'll attempt to do it without pandas.

```
orig = [["ID", "Header1", "Header2"], [1, "a1", "a2"], [2, "b1", "b2"]]

header = orig[0]

new_dict = {vals[0]: dict(zip(header[1:], vals[1:])) for vals in orig[1:] } 
print(new_dict)

new_dict[3] = {'Header1': 'c1', 'Header2': 'c2'} 
print(new_dict)
 
new_list = [header] + [ [k, *(new_dict[k][u] for u in header[1:]) ] for k in new_dict.keys() ]

print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
{1: {'Header1': 'a1', 'Header2': 'a2'}, 2: {'Header1': 'b1', 'Header2': 'b2'}}
{1: {'Header1': 'a1', 'Header2': 'a2'}, 2: {'Header1': 'b1', 'Header2': 'b2'}, 3: {'Header1': 'c1', 'Header2': 'c2'}}
[['ID', 'Header1', 'Header2'], [1, 'a1', 'a2'], [2, 'b1', 'b2'], [3, 'c1', 'c2']]
```

Comment: Do you think pandas is too heavy weight for this job?

Comment: @DanNeal No. I'm doing it just for fun or just in case someone is curious. In fact, I don't know how much it will impact performance.

Comment: I tested something based on  
juanpa.arrivillaga's comment above. 
So the way to get the new_list can be made shorter, like: `new_list = [header, *[[k, *v.values()] for k,v in new_dict.items()]]`

Answer (score 0):

This can do the job -

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = data[1:], columns = data[0]).T
df.columns = df.loc["ID"]
print(df.drop(index = "ID").to_dict()) # To print the dictionary
print(df.reset_index().T.values.tolist()) # To print the nested list
```

Output -

```
{1: {'Header1': 'a1', 'Header2': 'b1'}, 2: {'Header1': 'a2', 'Header2': 'b2'}}

[['ID', 'Header1', 'Header2'], [1, 'a1', 'a2'], [2, 'b1', 'b2']]
```

To get the list you shared in the question, you can just add a new row to the `df` dataframe and then uset the commented code to get that output.

Comment: However, what OP wanted to get back is more like `[["ID", "Header1", "Header2"], [1, "a1", "a2"], [2, "b1", "b2"]]` than `[['ID', 1, 2], ['Header1', 'a1', 'b1'], ['Header2', 'a2', 'b2']]` (as in your current answer). Do you need a transpose somewhere?

Comment: @qrsngky Sorry my bad, I forgot to tranpose the dataframe. Fixed it now!